# Rails CSS stylesheets overriding each other

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a clients.css and jobs.css in the assets/stylesheets location.

Each has a respective controller. Jobs was created with a scaffold after clients. The scaffolds.scss file is blank.

application.css is blank

When I code a change such as `body{color:black}` in the jobs.css, it changes the clients/index.html.erb view and the jobs/index.html.erb view.

What could be the reason for this? I would like to have separate .css files for jobs and clients..

Comment: In your `application.html.erb` layout, how are the stylesheets being required?

Comment: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> Sprockets concatenates all JavaScript files into one master .js file
>   and all CSS files into one master .css file.

What this means, of course, is that when you make a change to `jobs.css`, you'll see the same css being applied to every matching element throughout your application. All of those separate .css files are there to help you keep things organized from a human perspective, rather than from the perspective of your application.

You might want to just come up with different IDs and classes depending on your page (like `#body_client` and `#body_job`) to differentiate them, but you can see how this naming convention could get unwieldy as your app grows.

Having separate assets is possible, but not without some pain.

In `application.js`, remove:

```
//= require_tree
```

In `application.css`, remove:

```
*= require_tree
```

In `application.html.erb`, add the following:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", params[:controller], :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", params[:controller] %>
```

Create a new initializer file at `config/initializers/assets.rb` and add the following code:

```
%w( clients_controller jobs_controller ).each do |controller|
  Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += ["#{controller}.js.coffee", "#{controller}.css"]
end
```

That should get you set up with separate per page assets. Check the original [blog post](http://theflyingdeveloper.com/controller-specific-assets-with-rails-4/) for more details.

Comment: Yeah, I added an alternative as an edit, but it's kludgey. The real "solution" is to come up with a design that you like for all your pages. That way, your effort in both initial development and maintenance is minimal.

Comment: Yeah, makes sense about the design for all pages

Comment: Also, I wouldnt style the `body` in any of the css files except maybe `application.scss`. A common practice I use is to use a `<main></main>` in the views and just style that instead of the entire application body