# Rails loads all JS files and not only controller specific ones

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My application has many controllers and Rails creates a css and a js (coffee) file for each controller.

From what I understand Rails loads only the controller specific JS file (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline).

I have a feedback controller and in the view I load and external JS library with javascript_include_tag. In feedback.js I use this library. Works wonderful.

But now if I navigate to another controller I get a JS error saying that a function used in feedback.js is not found.

Why is Rails trying to load my feedback.js if im not in the feedback controller?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? You've linked a semi-archaic version of the Rails guide. Nonetheless, your version includes the following: "Starting with version 3.1, Rails defaults to concatenating all JavaScript files into one master.js file and all CSS files into one master .css file." See [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753945/rails-css-stylesheets-overriding-each-other/38754089#38754089) if you really want separate JS assets for each controller.

Answer (score 1):

Rails asset pipeline does not load controller specific JS files for each controller.  It loads all JS files required in `application.js` on every page.  By convention it creates a JS file named for the resource when you create a new resource, to help you organize your JS code as it relates to each controller's views.  But again, that JS code is loaded on every page that uses `application.js`, by default.

You can create controller specific JS files, but you have to define them in the precompile section of `application.rb`, and make sure they are not also included in `application.js`.

Example:

application.rb:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # ...
      config.assets.precompile += %w(feedback.js)
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your `application.js` you should remove the `//= require feedback`, which will keep `feedback.js` from loading by default.  Finally, you have to manually include `feedback.js` in the views that need it with a `javascript_include_tag`, just like you are doing with your extra library.